# SwiftUI NavigationLink in the TitleBar pushes the view twice, a Button doing the same thing is not

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

This is annoying. The Edit button in the NavigationBar pushes the View twice. I made a test button which behaves correctly doing the same thing:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailListPage: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var listName: ListNames

//    @State private var isEditDetailListPageShowing = false
@State private var selection: String? = nil

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text(listName.title ?? "")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()) {

            Text(listName.listDetail ?? "Nothing is set yet!")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding()
                .cornerRadius(12)
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: EditDetailListPage(listName: listName)) {
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text("Edit Page")
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Cancel")
            } .padding()
            //Edit List Detail
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: EditDetailListPage(listName: listName)) {
                Text("Edit")
            }

    }
    
}
}
```

The Text("Edit") right above is pushing the view twice.
The Button above it acts correctly. Would like to use the navigationbaritem instead of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Works well for me, on macos 11.4, xcode 12.5, target ios 14.5 and macCatalyst 11.3.
Probably some other code (or settings/system) that is causing the issue.
What system are you using? Show us the missing code and how you call the views. Let us know if the test code below does not work for you.

This is the test code I used:

```
@main
struct TestErrorApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct EditDetailListPage: View {
    var listName: [String]
    var body: some View {
        Text("EditDetailListPage")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            DetailListPage(listName: ["test var"])
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct DetailListPage: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var listName: [String]
    //  @State private var isEditDetailListPageShowing = false
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("header string")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding()) {
                Text("Nothing is set yet!")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .padding()
                    .cornerRadius(12)
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: EditDetailListPage(listName: listName)) {
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Edit Page")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text("Cancel")
                } .padding()
                //Edit List Detail
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: EditDetailListPage(listName: listName)) {
                    Text("Edit")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListFrontPage: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @State private var isAddNewListShowing = false
    
    var listNames: FetchRequest<ListNames>

    init() {
        listNames = FetchRequest<ListNames>(entity: ListNames.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ListNames.sort, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List() {
                Text("Accounts")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                ForEach (listNames.wrappedValue) { listName in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailListPage(listName: listName)) {
                        Text("\(listName.title ?? "")")
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                .onMove(perform: moveItem)
            }
            Spacer()
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: AddNewList()) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill").font(.system(size: 64))
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
            Label("Back", image: "")
        }, trailing: EditButton())
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Account Management"))
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { listNames.wrappedValue[$0] }.forEach(CoreDataHelper.sharedManager.deleteItems)
            
        }
    }
    
    private func moveItem(from offsets: IndexSet, to destination: Int)
    {
        print("From: \(String(describing: offsets)) To: \(destination)")
        // Make an array of items from fetched results
        var revisedItems: [ ListNames ] = listNames.wrappedValue.map{ $0 }
        
        // change the order of the items in the array
        revisedItems.move(fromOffsets: offsets, toOffset: destination )
                
        // update the userOrder attribute in revisedItems to
        // persist the new order. This is done in reverse order
        // to minimize changes to the indices.
        for reverseIndex in stride( from: revisedItems.count - 1,
                                    through: 0,
                                    by: -1 )
        {
            revisedItems[ reverseIndex ].sort =
                Int16( reverseIndex )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice work. Thanks for testing. This works fine on my 11.3 xcode 12.5 as well. Hard to duplicate. It's a core data project. There are several views b4 getting to the DetailPage. I am going to Edit my post and show the immediate view, calling view. Once again thanks for trying. At least I know it should work.

Comment: @JamesBond Edited the wrong post (edit your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67645023/edit), not someone's answer)